# Set up the Android-Facebook sdk for Netbeans

Tags: android, facebook, netbeans

I worked a lot lately on android stuff in my favorite IDE, NetBeans. It was a pain to simply set up the basic android sdk in it, but now i need to make an app with facbook connection. Is there a way to make the Facebook-related classes work with NetBeans? Has anyone done it? Thanks for any help, and sorry for my english!

Comment: **Updated Answer** Goto this link it shows how to integrate android with facebook [Link1](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/)

Comment: dude if my answer is helpful to u then u can vote up

Comment: Something very interesting happened on my way to the link, Rstar. It miraculously became an Eclipse tutorial. And we were searching for Netbeans tutorial, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find a solution to this problem many times when I found the solution provided by bali182. However I couldn't properly understand the solution so I decided to give more explanations about the it:

1. You need to create a new android project
2. get github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk (only facebook directory will be useful)
3. copy from facebook directory src to your root project src
4. copy from facebook directory res to your root project res
5. copy from facebook directory libs to your root project libs directory
6. right click on your project and properties
7. within properties, click on library left hand side menu entry
8. tick is library
9. then you can buil the project

Now you are good and can link the new created library to any android project. In order to link the library to your facebook project, you'll simply need to right click on your android project, click on library and add the facebook sdk library path.

The problem that I had at the begining was due to the fact that I was directly copying src, res, libs directly to my main project (phonegap project) and that caused issues when compiling it. Linking the newly created library to my main project was the key! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks to Rstar-s tutorial, i finally found the solution. I tought, that i need to install an extension, similar to the core Android SDK, but no, here is what you need to do:

1.) go to github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

2.) download the facebook directory ONLY! The other directories are only examples.

3.) Put the files from the src (you can copy the drawables too, if you want to) in the package, you are currently working with

4.) You are good to go, you can use the facebook "SDK"

Thank you RStar for the answer!