# Facebook Android SDK in Netbeans

Tags: cordova, netbeans

I'm used to developing in Netbeans, but the Facebook plugin for Android is only documented for Eclipse, which is a pain for Phonegap development (no html/js editor and generally just unhelpful for everything web related).

Wondering if anyone has managed to install the Facebook SDK for Android in Netbeans.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366755/set-up-the-android-facebook-sdk-for-netbeans

Comment: The link on that answer is dead, and I don't know where exactly I should put the files.

Answer (score 4):

I feel, setting up android on netbeans is the first step. 
http://www.nbandroid.org/p/installation.html

Refer to this link: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin
or do `git clone https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git`
which says:

If you plan on rolling this out on Android, please note that you will need to [generate a hash of your Android key(s) and submit those to the Developers page on Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/) to get it working. Furthermore, if you are generating this hash on Windows (specifically 64 bit versions), please use version 0.9.8e or 0.9.8d of [OpenSSL for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/list) and *not* 0.9.8k.

If you are planning a Native Facebook Android App:

Then you could download facebook plugin from this link:
https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-android-sdk-3.0.1.zip?campaign_id=282184128580929&placement=Android_SDK

You have lot of examples under samples folder.

I have not installed netbeans, but my guess is, the above steps should help you set it up.

Comment: Hey, I have already went through all those steps, I develop Phonegap on Netbeans already, the problem is now with plugins (namely the Facebook plugin...), Eclipse allows me to import plugins and add them to an Android project - all via an interface, what I want to know is include these plugins in Netbeans.

I just tried importing the project directly to Netbeans and tried to clean it, generating this error:
sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through an env var

Comment: Also, just checked my local.properties on Netbeans and the right path to the SDK is set...

Comment: A small update on this, I don't know if it was the new Netbeans version (7.3 at the time of this writing), but I imported my project on this Netbeans version and everything ran fine! No errors on my libraries at all. If you are still having problems with the latest Netbeans version, try putting the Facebook library file (.jr file) on your projects libraries folders.